# Cannot Use Repository - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll Error

Tags: c#, repository, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a simple Api using

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }   
}
```

I've built a very simple repository/interface. When I run it I get the following errors in VS2015 output:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll

The exception error is:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AwsApi.Models.Repository' while attempting to activate
>   'AwsApi.Controllers.DataController'.

I get this Information in the event viewer:

> The description for Event ID 1001 from source HttpPlatformHandler
>   cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not
>   installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You
>   can install or repair the component on the local computer.

I took out HttpPlatformHandler from dependencies and Startup to see if it made a difference and it didn't.

Here's my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Here's my Repository code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AwsApi.Models
{
    public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private MyContext _context;

        public Repository(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<tblQuotes>  GetAllQuotes()
        {
            return _context.tblQuotes.Take(10).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AwsApi.Models
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<tblQuotes> GetAllQuotes();
    }
}
```

Here's the Controller:

```
namespace AwsApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository _repository;

        public DataController(Repository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            return Json(_repository.GetAllQuotes());
        }
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs has:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
```

If I change the controller calling the context directly and bypassing the repository like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using AwsApi.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace AwsApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        private MyContext _context;

        public DataController(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            return Json(_context.tblBinQuotes.Take(10).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

It works and returns JSON data!

When it errors, it doesn't even touch the repository or the controller. I can't find a point where it fails.

I'm connecting to an existing SQL Db. I've tried it with and without a Mapper.

Have I missed something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You registered `IRepository` in `Startup.cs`, but requesting `Repository` in controller. Change controller constructor parameter type to `IRepository`:

```
public DataController(IRepository repository) {...}
```